# How to get entity for owner entity with spring boot jpa

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I want get list of comments with entity post for every item of comment:
I use this annotation :
For entity Post:

```
@JsonManagedReference
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "post", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();
```

For entity Comment

```
@JsonBackReference
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "post_id", nullable = false)
private Post post;
```

But always function of `findAll()` return just list of comments without entity post.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Fetch Type EAGER` if by default you want to load Post entity or if you will call get method then it will be load.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "post_id", nullable = false)
private Post post;
```

Comment: btw the single `@...ToOne` entity is `EAGER` by default so it would be sufficient just to remove  `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` and stay with simple `@ManyToOne`

Answer (score 0):

Change `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` to `@ManyToOne` by removing fetch.

You don't have to define fetch type in both sides.

Refer this great article : [jpa-hibernate-synchronize-bidirectional-entity-associations](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-hibernate-synchronize-bidirectional-entity-associations/)